# Animation supporting Internet explorer for flip book

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im working on an animated flip book, that uses css3 transforms and such and I'm struggling to get it working it ie using the code below. Does anyone know if there is a fix for this to force support? Here is a working version on codepen.

http://codepen.io/framp/pen/bBtuc

```
               -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s, margin .5s;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s, margin .5s;
                transition: transform .5s, margin .5s;
```

Comment: If u see `f12` console in I.E. Error is : `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'contains': object is null or undefined` in script: `document.documentElement.classList.contains( ...` so replace `contains` with `includes`

Answer (score 0):

Your options are either to implement two solutions - with CCS3 and without - or use an animation library, which automates this for you. [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), for example, uses CCS3 transforms when possible and high performance JS animations on older browsers. [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) on the other hand is a pure Javascript animation library, which will naturally work fine in both older and current browsers.